# Como atualizar o "personal access token" do github nos projetos antigos?

Tags: linux, git, github, token

Fala galera! Blz?
Estou com um problema ao tentar realizar o git push de alguns projetos antigos na minha máquina, pois o meu token de autenticação antigo do github expirou e eu criei um novo há duas semanas. Então, quando fui subir as modificações em um projeto antigo apareceu a seguinte mensagem:
**remote: Permission to fulanoDeTal/game-air-rescue.git denied to fuladoDeTal.
fatal: não foi possível acessar 'https://github.com/fulanoDeTal/game-air-rescue.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

Então fui no site do github e pesquisei o meu token e lá tinha uma mensagem assim:
**If you’ve lost or forgotten this token, you can regenerate it, but be aware that any scripts or applications using this token will need to be updated.**

Não sei como fazer isso para todos os projetos. Tenho que dar um git pull em todos os projetos antigos?

Observação: estou utilizando o Linux

Answer (score 0):

Tenta gerar outro token:

Caminho para gerar um novo token -> Settings/Developer settings/Personal access tokens/ Generate New Token

Após basta adicionar o mesmo ao seu (Terminal git/linux) ou (Nomes de Usuário e Senhas Armazenados -  Windows)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).